# How to populate response code in StackDriver ErrorReporting UI

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-error-reporting

Like the title suggests, I'm wondering how to populate the response code column in the GCP StackDriver ErrorReporting UI. Attached a screenshot for clarification.

I'm using Golang and the `cloud.google.com/go/errorreporting` package to report custom errors, with this following code.

```golang
client.Report(errorreporting.Entry{
    User:  username,
    Error: err,
})
```

I know there's an option to attach a `Req` field, but after reading the `errorreporting` source code, it's not clear how that would work. It looks like [the source code](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-go/blob/24f9f82cf8c5ed3c0303f34f76876365ce742aad/errorreporting/errors.go#L172-L179) doesn't actually read the response status code from the request object.

Any pointers appreciated.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Agreed, it looks like this isn't possible with the Go client today.

The client could be updated to populate the `HttpRequestContext.response_status_code` (Protobuff) field based on the `Entry.Req.Response.StatusCode` (Go) value, like

```
                RemoteIp:           r.RemoteAddr,
+               ResponseStatusCode: r.Response.StatusCode,
            },
```

The best option would be to file a feature request (or pull request) at https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-go/